# Matching text with regex/python - remove "=/r/" at line breaks

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code that isolates a chunk of text from an email:

```
for part in mail.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
        content = part.get_payload()
        message = re.compile(r'\%(.+?)\%', re.DOTALL).findall(content)
        print message
```

This finds the text perfectly, however, when it `prints`, I get something like this:

```
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et erat libe=\r\
nro. Ut lacinia ante euismod nibh feugiat pellentesque. Suspendisse vestibul=\r\
...
```

How do I go about removing the `=\r\` at the end of each line? Thank you!

Comment: First, are you sure you want to remove `'=\r\'` as opposed to removing `'=\r\n'` or replacing it with an actual newline? Second, I'm pretty sure there are no backslash or `r` characters there in the first place—if there were, the `repr` would show `libe=\\r\\n`, not `libe=\r\n`. There are CR and newline characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could we see the initial text it starts with?

From what I see at the moment you could modify your code to do the following;

```
for part in mail.walk():
    if part.get_content_type() == 'text/plain':
        content = part.get_payload()
        message = re.compile(r'\%(.+?)\%', re.DOTALL).findall(content)
        # This will just substitue the '=\r\' with nothing.
        message = re.sub(r'=\\r\\', '', message)
        print message
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should remove any "=\r\" in your text.

```
result = re.sub("=\\\\r\\\\", "", searchText)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using this regex:

```
message = re.compile(r'\%(.+?)\%', re.DOTALL).findall(content)
```

Which might be better stated as:

```
message = re.findall(r'\%(.+?)\%', content, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

In either case, findall produces a list of strings -- not a string as the result.

If you have a list of strings, you need to use a list comprehension:

```
>>> me
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.=\r', 'Ut lacinia ante euismod nibh feugiat pellentesque.=\r', 'Suspendisse vestibul=\r']
>>> [re.sub(r'=\r','',e) for e in me]
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.', 'Ut lacinia ante euismod nibh feugiat pellentesque.', 'Suspendisse vestibul']
```

Or just use strip or rstrip:

```
>>> [e.rstrip('\r') for e in me]
['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.', 'Ut lacinia ante euismod nibh feugiat pellentesque.', 'Suspendisse vestibul']
```

Answer (score 0):

If `print`ing the message gives you this:

> ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et erat libe=\r\nro. Ut lacinia ante euismod nibh feugiat pellentesque. Suspendisse vestibul=\r\n

… then you don't have any `\` characters, or `r` character, to remove. You have carriage-return characters, which Python shows as `\r` (carriage-return) characters. You've also got newlines, which Python shows as `\n`.

That's because you're seeing the `repr` of the string, not the `str`. Normally, `print x` prints the `str`… but the `str` of a `list` (or other collection) includes the `repr`, not the `str`, or each of its elements.

If you actually print the `str`, as in `print message[0]`, you will see something like this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras et erat libe=
>   ro. Ut lacinia ante euismod nibh feugiat pellentesque. Suspendisse vestibul=

So, you do not want to remove `'\r\`, or remove `\r\n`, or replace `\r\n` with a newline, or anything like that. The strings are already correct. (You can convert the Windows-style `\r\n` newlines to Unix-style `\n` if you want, but you don't have to.)

Except, of course, for the `=` characters at the end of each line. To fix that:

```
s.replace('=\r', '\r')
```

Or, to fix it for every string in a list:

```
[s.replace('=\r', '\r') for s in message]
```